# Show/Hide multiple DIVs with same class using radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a series of DIVs spread across the page. How can I use a single set of radio buttons at the top to hide/show all DIVs with the same class on the page?

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorShow" value="1" />
  <label for="csSelectorShow">Show</label>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorHideAll" value="2" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="csSelectorHideAll">Hide</label>
</form>

<div id="cs1" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 1</p>
</div>

<div id="cs2" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 2</p>
</div>

<div id="cs3" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target the radio and div you need with `querySelectorAll()` so that you can attach event to the radio and show/hide div based on the radio button value.

```js
var rad = document.querySelectorAll('[name=csr_selector]'); //get both radio button
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.csSelectorShow'); //get all div with the class
rad.forEach(function(r){
  r.addEventListener('change', function(){ 
    if(this.value == "1")
      div.forEach(d => d.style.display='block');
    else
      div.forEach(d => d.style.display='none');
  });
});
```

```css
.csSelectorShow{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorShow" value="1"/>
  <label for="csSelectorShow">Show</label>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorHideAll" value="2" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="csSelectorHideAll">Hide</label>
</form>


<div id="cs1" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 1</p>
</div>

<div id="cs2" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 2</p>
</div>

<div id="cs3" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 3</p>
</div>
```

Since you have updated the question by adding jQuery tag, here is the jQuery solution using `toggle()`:

```js
$('[name=csr_selector]').change(function(){
  $('.csSelectorShow').each(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.csSelectorShow{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorShow" value="1"/>
  <label for="csSelectorShow">Show</label>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorHideAll" value="2" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="csSelectorHideAll">Hide</label>
</form>


<div id="cs1" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 1</p>
</div>

<div id="cs2" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 2</p>
</div>

<div id="cs3" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways we can solve your problem, i prefer this way is some easy and understading.

```js
 $(function(){
            $('.csSelectorShow').hide();
              $('input:radio').change(function(){
                if($(this).val()==1){
                     $('.csSelectorShow').show();
                }else if($(this).val()==2){
                                $('.csSelectorShow').hide();

                }
              })            
        })
```

```css
.csSelectorShow{
 display:none; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorShow" value="1" />
  <label for="csSelectorShow">Show</label>
  <input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorHideAll" value="2" checked="checked"/>
  <label for="csSelectorHideAll">Hide</label>
</form>

<div id="cs1" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 1</p>
</div>

<div id="cs2" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 2</p>
</div>

<div id="cs3" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="csr_selector" id="csSelectorShowHide" value="1" />
<label for="csSelectorShow">Show/Hide</label>
</form>
<div>
 <div id="cs1" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 1</p>
 </div>
 <div id="cs2" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 2</p>
 </div>
 <div id="cs3" class="csSelectorShow">
  <p>Script 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#csSelectorShowHide').click(function(){
     $('.csSelectorShow').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This Solutions using jQuery

Comment: But there is no jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: Added jQuery tag to the question. However, this implementation doesn't have a way to toggle between on and off.